# Could not find implicit value for parameter p

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have a type class instance and want to use it implicitly but got following error message:

```
Error:(10, 29) not enough arguments for method format: (implicit p: ch.micarna.interface.Printable[ch.micarna.cats.Cat])String.
Unspecified value parameter p.
    val v = Printable.format(cat)
Error:(10, 29) could not find implicit value for parameter p: ch.micarna.interface.Printable[ch.micarna.cats.Cat]
    val v = Printable.format(cat)
```

The implementation of the type class looks as follow:
[image]

As you can see on the image, the implementation is imported from the package `import ch.micarna.instances._` where type class for `Cat` type is implemented.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't you import everything from object `PrintableInstances`?

Comment: I did it with `import ch.micarna.instances._`

Comment: Hm, doesn't seem so. `import ch.micarna.instances.PrintableInstances._` might do better.

Comment: Thanks it works now. Why `import ch.micarna.instances._` is not enought?

Comment: Your `implicit`s are defined inside the object. `import ch.micarna.instances._` only brings `PrintableInstances` to the scope.

Comment: So that after `import ch.micarna.instances._` you could do `import PrintableInstances._` (e.g. if you wanted to use other things defined under `ch.micarna.instances` as well).